# spring MVC: readonly & disabled

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this code in the JSP

```
<form:input  path="userBean.company.addressInfo.website" readonly="${activeField}" disabled="${activeField}" style="width:350px" htmlEscape="true"/>

    <input id="imageFile" type="file" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" onchange="uploadImageAction()" readonly="${activeField}" disabled="${activeField}" />
```

but when I check the source code in the browser

```
<input id="userBean.company.addressInfo.website" name="userBean.company.addressInfo.website" style="width:350px" type="text" value="website hidden"/>


<input id="imageFile" type="file" name="companyLogo" value="" onchange="uploadImageAction()" readonly="" disabled="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

so website is not readonly but imageFile si readonly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In HTML `disabled` and `readonly` are attributes that make the HTML-Element disabled/readonly just by there presence, no matter what the value for this element in HTML is!

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

so `<input ... disabled>`, `<input ... disabled="true">` and `<input ... disabled="disabled">` render all an disabled input field, *even `<input ... disabled="false">` should disable it*

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `imageFile` element is created using `html`, while the `website` element is created by html generated through Spring's `form:input` tag.

To make the `input` element generated by Spring's `form:input` tag `readonly` or `disabled`, you have to use the corresponding attribute from that tag, which may not necessarily match attribute names and values in html.

Refer the form tld documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

Basically, if you want to make a `form:input` tag `readonly`, add an attribute `readonly` with value `true`, if you want to make it `disabled`, add an attribute called `disabled` with value `true`.

```
<form:input  path="userBean.company.addressInfo.website" readonly="true" disabled="true" style="width:350px" htmlEscape="true"/>
```

You can of course use a variable like `activeField` to set values for the attributes, like you have in your example, just make sure the value is `true` when you want the attribute to apply.